# Feedback on Proper use of Community and the eternal List of X

Tags: discussion

I decided to do a test run with community wiki on

[How can I backup all of my tweets?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/657/how-can-i-backup-all-of-my-tweets)

instead of closing as "Not Constructive" since it's just asking for a list of backup services (to be fair back then even I voted on the question).

So I merged all answers into one. And listed it by type.

The pros so far I see in this is

- having a quick view of what sites are out there without discounting the effort given for finding the apps.

The cons

- if a post is made CW from the start, most users may not want to contribute (no rep to be gained)
- it could be an excuse to keeping list questions open
- someone needs to continually maintain it

A suggestion would be to push extended details (what each service does and their limitations) to separate answers. But then as seen with [Hidden features of Google Search](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/753/hidden-features-of-google-search) , one will not be able to control where the Table of Contents are shown (since we cannot force a user to accept a particular answer).

Also if there was a way to control where the contents show up. One could keep the ToC answer CW, leave the rest of the answers non-wiki and ensure users answer with details.

Is there any improvements/frowns to this? I think this is my umpteenth try working at the [webapp-rec](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/webapp-rec) problem but I will [just keep swimming](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CmyUkm2qlhA).

Answer (score 1):

More and more these list of questions seem to be great fodder to include as part of the tag wikis themselves.

For the list of Twitter backup services, you could include that in the tag wiki under a "Ways to backup your tweets" or "Backup methods".

> ### Twitter
>
> Excerpt blah blah
>
> #### Backup services and method
>
> - example.com
> - example.com
> - insert into pigeon

For those that are "I want an alternative to Schmeelpr" we can follow that same track and include a section titled, "Alternatives". If those services already have a tag, make use of the reference.

> ### Schmeelpr
>
> Excerpt blahdiblahdiblooblurp
>
> #### Alternatives
>
> - [mollickr](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mollickr)
> - [westofnorth](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/westofnorth)
> - [bananaramalamadingdong](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bananaramalamadingdong)